# Are there infinite many two sided prime numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

A prime number $p=\overline{a_na_{n-1}\ldots a_1a_0}$ is called a two sided prime number if its reverse representation $q=\overline{a_0a_1\ldots a_{n-1}a_n}$ is a prime number too.

Are there infinitely many two sided prime numbers?

Comment: Those are called emirps and your question is a (presumably very difficult) open problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emirp

Comment: @Wojowu the OEIS reserves the term *emirp* for primes whose reversal is a *different* prime, so not including $2,3,5,7,11,101$ and others. http://oeis.org/A006567 The numbers Ali asks about, OEIS calls *reversible primes*. http://oeis.org/A007500

Comment: @GerryMyerson Good catch, my bad.

Comment: More generally, are there infinitely many primes such that at least one non-trivial permutation of their digits preserves the primality?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN Perhaps Zhang et al.'s results on prime constellations might be of use here. I'm thinking of something like, take the set of permutations of some finite string of $k$ digits $N$ and pick out a large admissible tuple out of it. Perhaps the methods can be used to show infinitely many primes are of the form $a10^k+N',a10^k+N''$ for two permutations of $N'.N''$.

Comment: The word 'decimal' belongs somewhere in this post.

Comment: Pretty much _any_ statement of the form "there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $f(p)$ is also prime" for a given function $f$ is beyond current technology to establish if $f$ is not something totally degenerate (e.g. a constant function or the identity function).  The case $f(p)=p+2$ being the most famous, of course.

Answer (score 5):

For many variants of this question the answer seems to be not known but at least this question in the comments

> More generally, are there infinitely many primes such that at least one non-trivial permutation of their digits preserves the primality? – Sylvain JULIEN

in binary has the answer Yes. Thanks to @AlexeiKulikov for the improved argument.

Use

- (i) Prime number theorem
- (i
  ii) Pigeonhole principle

By (i) there are at least $c (2^n/n)$ primes in $[2^{n-1},2^n)$ whose number of 1s is in the interval 
$[1,n]$.

By (ii) there are two primes in $[2^{n-1},2^n)$ with the same number of 1s.

Comment: Sorry, what you did in the second step? Most numbers are not primes as well so it may well be that for primes their digit sums are always very small. In any case you don't need anything like this because there are at most $n$ digit sums and the muber of primes is much, much more (asymptotically $2^n/n$) and this actually works for any base -- there are at most $n^{b-1}$ different sets of digits.

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov you are right... fixed now

Comment: Can Maynard's work about primes with missing digits be of any use to show a similar result for base ten?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN I guess I wrote it in my comment -- you don't need anything, there are at most $n^9$ sets of $n$ digits and the number of primes is $\sim 10^n/n$ which is much larger.